# Creating a program to output 4 of the triangular square numbers

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm creating a program to just output the first four triangular square numbers (1,36,1225,41616), but its only outputting "Square Triangular Number 1 is: 0". What am I doing wrong? Still new to C++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    for(int i=1;i<=4;i++);
    {
        int x=1;
        int test=0;
        test+=(1/32)*((pow((17+12*sqrt(2)),x))+(pow((17-12*sqrt(2)),x)-2));
        cout<<"Square Triangular Number 1 is: "<<test<<endl;
        x+=1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

1. `(1/32)` does [integer division](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html).
2. 1/32 is equal to 0.03125.
3. 0.03125 gets truncated to 0 due to integer division discarding the fractional part of the number.
4. `test += 0 * <other_computations>`.
5. 0 multiplied by any other number is still 0.
6. `test = 0`.

Also, your for loop does nothing 4 times in a row, just saying.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct if you feel it has helped you @JackBunzow! (Checkmark below down arrow)

Answer (score 1):

Two things are giving that output:

1. `for(int i=1;i<=4;i++);`

> The extra semicolon makes the for loop useless and your code inside
>   the braces will be executed only once.

2. `test+=(1/32) * (the rest)`

> 1/32 is an integer division which result is 0 * (the rest) is simply 0.

Comment: Thank you so much!